# Angular 2 form (ViewChild) controls are empty in unit test

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing

Template HTML:

```html
<form 
  #myForm="ngForm"
  novalidate>
  <input 
    #myCtrl
    required
    type="input" 
    name="myCtrl" 
    id="myCtrl"
    [(ngModel)]="value">
</form>
```

Component has:

```ts
@ViewChild('myForm') myForm: NgForm;
```

In my tests, when I console.log the following, I get {}

```
fixture.debugElement.componentInstance.myForm.controls
```

The form also has `errors: null` and `status 'VALID'` despite the fact that the form should contain an invalid FormControl. Is it possible to unit test forms when they are configured with ViewChild rather than FormBuilder? Is there a way to do it with my ViewChild setup?

Comment: Can you include test in your question?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `novalidate` attribute? My understanding is that those should only be used for model-driven forms, not template-driven ones